# Gitlab runner distributed caching not working

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-runner

I am trying to setup distributed caching in my gitlab runner. I have changed the config.toml as specified in the docs https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-runners-caching.

But it keeps showing
`No URL provided, cache will be not uploaded to shared cache server. Cache will be stored only locally.`

Anyone has any idea what could be the issue or how i can debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the error message I thought runner wasn't recognising s3 cache option.
But when u give the wrong config same error seems to be thrown. In my case i had given https:// in the ServerAddress which was not needed.